# How to animate jLabel from one side to another side of Jframe using netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, paint, thread-sleep

I want to create a small application.In my application I have `jLabel1` and `Jbutton1`. I want to animate `jLabel1` from one side to another side using `jButton` click. I don't know how to *call* it in the `jButton1ActionPerformed` to create the animation of `jLabel1`. I have done a paint application code which is giving as following.

Here is my code:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;

   g2.drawString("ancd", x, y);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(""+e);
    }
    x+=10;
    if(x>this.getWidth())
            {
               x=0;
            }
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: you may find useful [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467230/jlabel-animation-in-jpanel) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545744/java-animate-jlabel)

Comment: @guleryuz both the codes are not getting understand to me can you please make proper solution for it?

Comment: @S.V You can take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

To keep things simple, you may use the Swing timer for the animation. However, if I were you I wouldn't move a JLabel. But instead I will draw directly onto the JPanel and keep a set of positions (x and y for the image). In the timer, update the position and repaint it.

Since you wanted to move a JLabel across the screen, you can do something like this:

```
class DrawingSpace extends JPanel{

    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;
    private Timer timer;    

    public DrawingSpace(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
        initComponents();
        add(label);
        add(button);    
    }

    public void initComponents(){
        label = new JLabel("I am a JLabel !");
        label.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        button = new JButton("Move");

        //Move every (approx) 5 milliseconds        
        timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener(){  
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                //Move 1 px everytime
                label.setLocation(label.getLocation().x, label.getLocation().y+1);  
            }               
        });     
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(!timer.isRunning())
                    timer.start();
                else
                    timer.stop();   
            }   
        }); 
    }
}
```

Then the class to run the program:

```
class Mover{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {     // Run the GUI codes on the EDT
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Some Basic Animation");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new DrawingSpace());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);             
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

If you plan to implement using `paint()`, I would say you probably should be overriding `paintComponents(Graphics g)` instead of `paint(Graphics g)` from the Java Components. 
Also do not clutter your paint method with things like `Thread.sleep()` it may freeze your UI. The paint method should only contain codes needed for painting and nothing else.

Comment: (1+) for using a Timer, overriding paintComponent() and getting rid of Thread.sleep(). @sv When using animation you would also need to set the Layout to null otherwise the label will jump back to its default position the layout manager is ever invoked (ie resize the frame). This means you need to set the size/location of the label manually. You may instead want to consider using the [Drag Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/) which was designed for this purpose.

Comment: if(!timer.isRunning()) +++